# I need to be able to mark a rich text editor with a default value as dirty

Tags: ckeditor, xpages

I have an existing `Xpage` application that sets the default value of a rich text field based on a look up to another document.  The initial problem was that, unless the user entered something into the field, the default value was not saved.  I was able to solve this by adding `"xc:DirtyEditor"` to the page.  Now that I have upgraded to `Windows 2008`,`Domino 9.01FP3` and added the extension library, this code is causing problems with another part of the page (Fields with partial refresh stopped working).  Is there another way to mark the editor as dirty?

Answer (score 1):

Per IBM there has been a change to the editor in the latest release that is interfering with the partial update of the other fields.  They have turned it over to engineering.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an XPage "dirty" with CSJS code `XSP._setDirty(true,"")`.

Your case looks like you want to set the XPages dirty every time. Your XPage's source code could start then with

```
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    enableModifiedFlag="true">
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onClientLoad"
        submit="false"
        script="XSP._setDirty(true,'')" />
```